# Can't build npgsql from source

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

1. download zip from https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql
2. unzip
3. Open Npgsql.sln
4. Build Solution
5. Have many errors

```
1>------ Build Started: Project: Npgsql.SourceGenerators, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\test\Npgsql.Specification.Tests\Npgsql.Specification.Tests.csproj (in 335 ms).
1>C:\Users\LocalUser\.nuget\packages\microsoft.build.tasks.git\1.1.1\build\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets(25,5): warning : Cannot find repository with a working directory containing the "D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\src\Npgsql.SourceGenerators" directory.
1>C:\Users\LocalUser\.nuget\packages\microsoft.build.tasks.git\1.1.1\build\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets(48,5): warning : Cannot find repository with a working directory containing the "D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\src\Npgsql.SourceGenerators" directory.
1>C:\Users\LocalUser\.nuget\packages\microsoft.sourcelink.common\1.1.1\build\Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.targets(53,5): warning : Source control information not available - link created on source files is empty.
1>D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\src\Npgsql.SourceGenerators\TypeHandlerSourceGenerator.cs(11,34,11,35): error CS1514: Requires "{"
1>D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\src\Npgsql.SourceGenerators\NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilderSourceGenerator.cs(9,34,9,35): error CS1514: Requires "{"
1>D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\src\Npgsql.SourceGenerators\EmbeddedResource.cs(5,34,5,35): error CS1514: Requires "{"
1>D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\src\Npgsql.SourceGenerators\TypeHandlerSourceGenerator.cs(129,2,129,2): error CS1513: Requires "}"
1>D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\src\Npgsql.SourceGenerators\EmbeddedResource.cs(26,2,26,2): error CS1513: Requires "}"
1>D:\MyCode\C#\npgsql-main\src\Npgsql.SourceGenerators\NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilderSourceGenerator.cs(120,2,120,2): error CS1513: Requires "}"
1>Building project "Npgsql.SourceGenerators.csproj" completed with an error.
```

Comment: Might need to restore NuGet packages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-packages-in-visual-studio

Comment: I have these settings. And these settings don't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to install the latest version of Visual Studio, the link is the answer from the developers:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/5038